I'm trying to instrument a Microsoft (Bing) Ads UET conversion goal and I'm confused
I'm trying to instrument a Microsoft Ads UET Event and I find their instructions confusing.  Let's say I'm creating a conversion goal in the UI and I choose the "Subscribe" category.
Screenshot of category configuration
Then I name the conversion "Free Trial" and I want to give every conversion the value of $1.
Screenshot of conversion name and value configuration
The base UET tag is already installed.
It prompts me to set the parameters for my conversion goal, and for some reason it pre-populates the action to "purchase"?
Screenshot of conversion goal code
This is the function definition it asks me to use:
<script>
function uet_report_conversion() {
     window.uetq = window.uetq || [];
     window.uetq.push('event', 'purchase', {});
}
</script>

And then of course I would call uet_report_conversion() afterwards
I don't understand what "purchase" refers to in the context of my conversion goal.  Also, it doesn't seem to include any parameters for the value.  Am I expected to set all these parameters myself based on how I've configured the conversion goal?
Instead of "purchase" should I use the name of my event, "Free Trial"?  In some other working examples I've seen, the spaces seem to be replaced with underscores, so "free_trial"?
I'm using a Custom HTML tag in Google Tag Manager, I've tried using the Microsoft's chrome extension to test the event.  It comes up, but just with the details that I've put into the code, how can I be sure it will register with the conversion goal I created in the UI?
